# JSON.parse() is not converting my PHP string to a JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, php

I have used `json_encode()` to echo an associative array from PHP to JavaScript through this $.post method:

```
$.post("php/myfile.php", {}, function(data){
    exercises = data;
    //exercises = json.parse(data);   // console -> Uncaught ReferenceError: json is not defined
    alert(typeof exercises);          // alerts -> String
    alert(exercises);                 // alerts -> {"1":"Bench Press","2":"Squat","3":"Deadlift"}
    alert(json.stringify(exercises)); // console -> Uncaught ReferenceError: json is not defined
});
```

For some reason I can't convert the string to a JavaScript associative array using `json.parse()`.

**What's my issue?**

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: `exercises = JSON.parse(data);`

Comment: @Amber You can see the console errors and alerts errors

Comment: @ArunPJohny tried that as you can see. it isn't working

Comment: @NateMay no... look at the case `JSON` not `json`

Comment: Wow, didn't know it was case sensitive. thanks all

Answer (score 2):

You can pass `json` as the dataType to the ajax call so that jQuery will pass the converted value

```
$.post("php/myfile.php", {}, function (exercises) {
    alert(typeof exercises); // alerts -> String
    alert(exercises);
}, 'json');
```

In your code the problem is the case of `json`, it should be `JSON.parse()` not `json.parse()`